# Repeated calls to getters in Many to Many relationship fetches: Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, lazy-loading

I have a scenario of Many to Many relationship with extra attributes-

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name="policy_county")
public class PolicyCounty {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="policy_county_id")
    private long policyStateId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="policy_id")
    private InsurancePolicy policy;



    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "county_id")
    private County county;

    @Column(name="cost",nullable = false)
    private double cost;


    public long getPolicyStateId() {
        return policyStateId;
    }

    public InsurancePolicy getPolicy() {
        System.out.println("Policy County: getPolicy() called");
        return policy;
    }

    public County getCounty() {
        System.out.println("Policy county: getCounty() called");
        return county;
    }

    public double getCost() {
        return cost;
    }
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "insurance_policy")
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class InsurancePolicy {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="policy_id")
    private long policyId;

    @Column(name="policy_name",nullable = false,unique = true)
    private String policyName;

    //Short description
    @Column(name="policy_description",nullable = false)
    private String policyDescription;

    //Long description
    @Column(name="choose_description",nullable = false)
    private String chooseDescription;


    //many policies can belong to one category
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id", nullable = false)
    private Company company;

    //many policies can belong to one category
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="category_id",nullable=false)
    private Category category;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "queriedPolices",fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    private Set<User> usersQueried=new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "policy", cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REMOVE},fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<PolicyCounty> policyCounties = new HashSet<>();

    public long getPolicyId() {
        return policyId;
    }

    public String getPolicyName() {
        return policyName;
    }

    public String getPolicyDescription() {
        return policyDescription;
    }

    public String getChooseDescription() {
        return chooseDescription;
    }

    public Company getCompany() {
        System.out.println("InsurancePolicy.getCompany() called");
        return company;
    }

    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public Set<User> getUsersQueried() {
        return usersQueried;
    }

    public Set<PolicyCounty> getPolicyCounties() {
        System.out.println("Insurance policy getPolicyCounties called");
        return policyCounties;
    }
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name="county")
public class County {

    @Id
    @Column(name="countyid")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long countyId;

    @Column(name="countyname",nullable = false,unique = true)
    private String countyName;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "adminId", nullable = false)
    private Admin admin;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "county", cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REMOVE},fetch = FetchType.LAZY,orphanRemoval = true) //orphan removal is set to true so that the relationship can be removed
    private Set<PolicyCounty> policyCounties = new HashSet<>();

    public County() {
    }

    public long getCountyId() {
        return countyId;
    }

    public String getCountyName() {
        return countyName;
    }

    @JsonIgnoreProperties("policyCounties") //This prevents the fetch of the admin when insurance policy getPolicyCounty is called, which results in unnecessary fetches of the admin, category and other related entities
    public Admin getAdmin() {
        return admin;
    }


    public Set<PolicyCounty> getPolicyCounties() {
        System.out.println("County getPolicyCounties called");
        return policyCounties;
    }

    public void setCountyId(long countyId) {
        this.countyId = countyId;
    }

    public void setCountyName(String countyName) {
        this.countyName = countyName;
    }

    public void setAdmin(Admin admin) {
        this.admin = admin;
    }

    public void setPolicyCounties(Set<PolicyCounty> policyCounties) {
        this.policyCounties = policyCounties;
    }
}
```

Now, I have a service method which is calling the method-

```
  County county=this.countyRepository.findById(countyId).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("County with id "+countyId+" not found"));

        Set<PolicyCounty> policyCounties=county.getPolicyCounties();
```

**Problem-**
When the **getPolictCounties()** method is called, the getPolicy() and getCounty() methods of the PolicyCounty class get called repeatedly. Also, the related entities (company of policy then admin of company) of the **policy** are also fetched repeatedly even when **I am using LAZY fetch every where.** Although I get the results as desired but so many unnecessary fetches are slowing down the operation. I am not able to understand why **LAZY FETCH** is not working here. Please help!